# VS2019 Xamarin iOS Simulator 'Failed to install'

Tags: windows, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to use the Xamarin iOS Simulator and get this error when trying to run the app:
[image: v]

Logs for VS:

```
Launching...
Using Xcode 11.3 found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Xamarin.Hosting: Xamarin.Hosting
Xamarin.Hosting:     Version: 3064e2c463 (d16-3)
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode: /Applications/Xcode.app
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode Version: 11.3
Xamarin.Hosting:     Verbosity: 1
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/CoreSimulator
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/DTDeviceKitBase
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/DVTKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/DTDeviceKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/DTXConnectionServices
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework/DVTSourceControl
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTServices.framework/DVTServices
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTPortal.framework/DVTPortal
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/DVTDocumentation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalyticsClient.framework/DVTAnalyticsClient
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework/DVTAnalytics
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SourceKit.framework/SourceKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEProducts.framework/IDEProducts
Xamarin.Hosting: Simulator watchdogs are already disabled for 'iOS 13.3 (17C45) - iPhone 8'.
Xamarin.Hosting: Launching simulator application 'com.apple.iphonesimulator'
Xamarin.Hosting: Booting iPhone 8...
Xamarin.Hosting: Booted iPhone 8 successfully.
Xamarin.Hosting: No need to boot (already booted): iPhone 8
Xamarin.Hosting: Installing /Users/joespeers/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DevoApp.iOS/6a57dd827b8f10d2b20b2435abacdb1b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DevoApp.iOS.app with Bundle Identifier com.speersoft.DevoAppTest on 'iOS 13.3 (17C45) - iPhone 8'...
Xamarin.Hosting: Installed 'com.speersoft.DevoAppTest' from /Users/joespeers/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DevoApp.iOS/6a57dd827b8f10d2b20b2435abacdb1b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DevoApp.iOS.app
Xamarin.Hosting: Could not find any potentially troublesome weak load commands.
Xamarin.Hosting: The bundle id com.speersoft.DevoAppTest was successfully installed.
Xamarin.Hosting: Creating shared memory for:
__XAMARIN_DEBUG_PORT__=52107
Xamarin.Hosting: Created shared memory token: 449555
Xamarin.Hosting: Created shared memory id: 65536
Xamarin.Hosting: Mapped shared memory: 0x10a2eb000 for key 449555 and id 65536
Xamarin.Hosting: Launching com.speersoft.DevoAppTest on 'iOS 13.3 (17C45) - iPhone 8'
Xamarin.Hosting: Could not launch the app 'com.speersoft.DevoAppTest' on the device 'iOS 13.3 (17C45) - iPhone 8': The request to open "com.speersoft.DevoAppTest" failed., will try to reinstall the app
Xamarin.Hosting: Installing /Users/joespeers/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DevoApp.iOS/6a57dd827b8f10d2b20b2435abacdb1b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DevoApp.iOS.app with Bundle Identifier com.speersoft.DevoAppTest on 'iOS 13.3 (17C45) - iPhone 8'...
Xamarin.Hosting: Installed 'com.speersoft.DevoAppTest' from /Users/joespeers/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DevoApp.iOS/6a57dd827b8f10d2b20b2435abacdb1b/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DevoApp.iOS.app
Xamarin.Hosting: Could not find any potentially troublesome weak load commands.
```

Core Simulator log:
https://pastebin.com/LTicwbDa

Any help would be much appreciated

I have attempted the suggested fixes here:
[Xamarin.iOS: Cannot run after Visual Studio 2019 Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665600/xamarin-ios-cannot-run-after-visual-studio-2019-update)

Comment: Hi , have a try with cleaning your application folder and rebuilding it .

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work

Comment: 1) Try a different simulator, and also does it work on an actual iOS device? 2) Did it just stop working, what changed since the last time you were able to launch the app? 3) If you try it with a blank app, are you able to build it onto the simulator?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 1) I have tried it for iPhone 7,8 and 11 all on iOS 13.3, and get the same outcome. I cannot currently test it on a device as I am accessing the machine remotely, but i'll try that as soon as I can. 2) I have just started using Xamarin so this is my first attempt using the simulator. VS and Xcode are updated. 3) I have tried on a blank app and it still doesn't work!

Comment: @JoeSpeers Do you check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows) to setup the environment of development ?

Comment: Yeah I've done all the stuff on that page, and I've got the most up to date version of vs.

Comment: @JoeSpeers Okey , it's strange . If other solutions will update here later :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Cannot figure out how to fix it.
I updated Visual studio to version 16.8.3, Xamarin.IoS (on windows) to 14.6.0.15 and Xamarin 16.8.000.260
On Mac, I have installed Xcode 13 (cause I had 12 and 12.2 was requestd and could not find a way to install 12.2, so got 13)
Used automatic Mac Provisioning
I upgraded because I had same problem with previous version...