# How do I fix 'error HE0042' when trying to launch a Xamarin application in iOS 12 and below

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

I'm getting the following error when trying to launch a Xamarin.iOS application on iOS 12 and below (iOS 13 and above does launch the application without issue):

Debug output:

```
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.companyname.App1' on the device 'iOS 12.2 (16E226) - iPhone 8 Plus': The request to open "com.companyname.App1" failed.
```

Simulator System.Log

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B80099F4-F084-4872-A08A-87BD762045BF[2469] (UIKitApplication:com.companyname.App1[0x3536][2491][3415]): removing service since it exited with consistent failure - OS_REASON_EXEC
```

This error even occurs on a newly generated application using VS for Mac or Rider.

Things I tried without any result:

- Erase All Content and Settings in the simulator (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65978/debugger-wont-start-app-on-ios-device)
- Reinstalling CoreSimulator ([Xamarin.iOS: Cannot run after Visual Studio 2019 Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665600/xamarin-ios-cannot-run-after-visual-studio-2019-update))
- Clean Project, delete bin & obj folders & rebuild project

Is there anyone that experienced the same issue and how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a similar issue https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7711#issuecomment-580601147 and you could check Jon's solution .

Answer (score 2):

In the iOS project properties in Visual Studio under 'iOS Build' I checked 'Use the concurrent garbage collector'.
That handled it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well in my debug iphone simulator builds. The fix, for me, was to set the project's iOS Bundle Signing -> Custom Entitlements to Entitlements.plist. This will force the application to be signed.